# How to trigger an directive after a module out of my main module in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, fiddler, directive

I'm new in AngularJS and a little confused with directive things.
In the code below I need to make an input field with a directive which is in an outsource module and focus on it with my custom directive.
**Be careful I can not change the outsource module...**

*myHtml.html*

```
<body ng-app="main" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <my-field></my-field>
</body>
```

*Outsource.js*

```
var app2 = angular.module('pain', []);
app2.directive('myField', [function() {
    return {
        scope.f = 'focus-me';
    },
    template: 'name: <input type="text" class="{{f}}"/>' +
        '<br/>' +
        'input class is: \"{{f}}\"'
}
}]);
```

*myApp.js*

```
var app1 = angular.module('main', ['pain']);
app1.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.state = true;
}]);
app1.directive('focusMe', ['$timeout', '$parse', function($timeout, $parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.$watch(scope.state, function() {
                console.log('value=', scope.state);
                if (scope.state === true) {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        element[0].focus();
                    }, 20);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

**Fiddle**
[fiddler](https://fiddle.jshell.net/mon9xcqw/1/)

It would be ok with something like this code below but I can not change the outsource code.
**It works**
[fiddler](https://fiddle.jshell.net/mon9xcqw/2/)
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 0):

you defintely have to fix the code in *Outsource.js* for what you want to do to work. There are a few things wrong with it. Checkout my comments for explanations:

**Outsource.js - as it is in your question**

```
var app2 = angular.module('pain', []);
app2.directive('myField', [function() {
    return {
        /* directive scope needs to be added as a parameter to the angular directive link function before you can use it. */
        scope.f = 'focus-me';
    },
    // Your template property should be in your return object
template: 'name: <input type="text" class="{{f}}"/>' +
        '<br/>' +
        'input class is: \"{{f}}\"'
}
}]);
```

**Outsource.js - what it should be**

```
var app2 = angular.module('pain', []);

app2.directive('myField', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: 'name: <input type="text" class="{{f}}"/>'+
          '<br/>'+
          'input class is: \"{{f}}\"',
    link: function (scope) {
          scope.f='focus-me';
    },

    controller: [function ($scope) {
       // Do Awesome stuff in/with $scope here
    }]
  };
});
```

So tell the person that wrote the code in Outsource.js to fix it otherwise you can't achieve what you want to achieve.